# Safari 8 youtube html5 player fullscreen issue

Tags: ios, html, youtube, safari

Screen goes flickering and freezes my new Macbook Air(2015) while playing some youtube videos in fullscreen mode in safari 8. This issue was found with youtube HTML5 player. Flickering does not occur when there in an overlay of ad or player settings above the player and flickering stops on cursor movement.

Does anyone have any idea on solving this issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeXmqSHP8o4